# Move Keyboard Up Issue on iOS 11 iPhone 6 are earlier model

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview, uikeyboard

I'm using below method to move my 'UITextView' up when user clicks on it. But this works on iPhone 7 and iPhone X but when I tried it on iPhone 6, 5s then textView didn't move up.
Please help me with correct way to move keyboard up.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func startAvoidingKeyboard() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(_onKeyboardFrameWillChangeNotificationReceived(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    func stopAvoidingKeyboard() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func _onKeyboardFrameWillChangeNotificationReceived(_ notification: Notification) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {    
            return
                }

            let keyboardFrameInView = view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
            let safeAreaFrame = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom)
            let intersection = safeAreaFrame.intersection(keyboardFrameInView)

            let animationDuration: TimeInterval = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0, options: animationCurve, animations: {
                self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom = intersection.height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use IQKeyboardManager library for this... thats best

Comment: what's the os version of 6s and 5 ?

Comment: Please review the code, it has bracket mistakes...

Comment: @IgnacioAra Can you please tell where.

Comment: @arash iPhone 6s and 5 both on iOS 11

Comment: @NITESH check line `let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {    
            return
                }` it has to return error somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11 and later your code works fine but for earlier version you should use `NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame` instead of `NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame`

Comment: did you check DidChangeFrame ?

Comment: what? How to check for that ?

Comment: ignore os version and do what i said and check the result

Comment: What to check ?

Comment: check if textview moves up or not

Comment: it moves up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Please check version for iPhone 6, 5s.

It will only work if the version is equal to 11.0 or higher

Comment: Yes its on iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing this like that ? 
i would recommend using constraint animations to animate your constraint every time you touch the 'UITextView' (so that it moves),  you can read that answer I gave someone else on how to animate a constraint ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49721100/9514389) )

now have you heard about CocoaPods ? there are some useful libraries that you can use to animate your app (like [HERO](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero)) .

**If you do not know what  is cocoa pods or how to install it** , check out this video ([Cocoa Pods Tutorial - How to install and setup Cocoa Pods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNKVVBN2JN0))

Also sometime you want to do specific animations or specific things (Whatever is in your Head) on only one type of device (let say only the iPhone 8  and nothing else ) ; for that you can use [Device Kit](https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit) I would suggest you read it

Hope i was able to help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        let info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardHeight = ((info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size.height)! + self.extraPadding

        let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0)
        self.scrollView?.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: Notification)
{
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    scrollView?.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

This is how I adapt the content area of a scrollview when the keyboard is shown/hidden. You should be able to adjust the content area of a UITextView in the same fashion.